# Why is $1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}$ linearly independent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, extension-field

I have a basic question about the proof of "Every finite field extension is algebraic".

Given the extension $K\subset L$  with $n:=[L:K]$ and $a \in L$, the proof says, that we have a linearly dependent set $1,a,a^2, ...,a^{n+1}$, because their quantity  $n+1$ is bigger than $n$, the dimension of the vectorspace of $L$ over $K$.

But why we can conclude this only by looking at the dimension? Otherwise why we can say, that $1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}$ would form a basis for the vectorspace $L$ over $K$. I mean for example  given $a^2=a^3=...=a^{n+1}$, it wouln't be correct that $1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}$ is a linearly independent set. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: If $a^2=a^3$, or such,  then you have found a linear dependence as desired.

Comment: By definition of dimension, any subset of more than $n$ vectors is linearly dependent.

Comment: The point here is that you can't have $n+1$ linearly independent vectors in a vector space of dimension $n$. That's what "dimension $n$" means.

Comment: Certainly, $\{1,a,...,a^{n-1}\}$ is not in general a basis. But surely you don't need it for that proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, when a vector space has "dimension $n$", it means that any linearly independent subset has cardinality $n$ or less. Which means that if you have a set with $n+1$ elements, it is linearly dependent.

Having an arbitrary set of $n$ elements does not guarantee that you have a basis, because maybe they are linearly dependent; but that's not what your text says.